# C(++) type name function/macro

Tags: c++, c

Is there a macro to return (ideally as a `const char*` or indeed `cont char *const`) the typename of its parameter or some information on it?

This is at ***compile time***, not runtime, so C++'s typeinfo will not do. I run with `-fno-rtti` anyway.

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: The macro processor doesn't even know you're writing C, let alone types. Also, type names don't *have* a standardized string representation.

Comment: You can still have a look at [this thread "String representation of a type"](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t742758-string-representation-of-a-type.html) which contains a discussion (with Scott Meyers! ^^) and some links (notably [this implementation of `Printtype`](http://geometrica.saclay.inria.fr/team/Marc.Glisse/tmp/printtype.cpp)). (Source: Scott Meyers' article _Appearing and Disappearing consts in C++_)

Comment: Also please give me a valid reason to remove RTTI in 2013.

Comment: @kbok Speed maybe? (I'm all for dynamism, just guessing.)

Comment: @H2CO3 There are no speed implications in removing RTTI - only in choosing not to use it.

Comment: @kbok I've read somewhere on SO that RTTI still has a performance overhead even if unused. So is that assertion wrong?

Comment: @H2CO3 Do you have a link?

Comment: Thanks @AndyProwl I had hoped there'd be a (perhaps compiler dependent) thing to do this! The compiler has the information! Why stop at sizeof :P.

Comment: @gx_ Actually that looks like an almost complete solution – one would only need to add demangling for custom type names (which is unfortunately compiler dependent), the result looks quite promising.

Comment: @H2CO3 *"So is that assertion wrong?"* - At least I cannot imagine any reasonable way for this to not be wrong. Maybe you messed up RTTI with exceptions in your memory?

Comment: @ChristianRau Nah, I clearly remember having heard that about RTTI... whatever, nevermind.

Comment: RTTI uses a lot of memory.  It has to track metrics for every defined class, which if you use template classes like `std` or `boost`, can be much more than you think.  IIRC, this was on the order of megabytes in an application I worked on.  It should have no speed impact if not directly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't.

C++11 does have the `__func__` identifier inside function definitions, which produces a string variable with the function name.  Most C++ compilers have variations on this to have "decorated" function names.

Comment: GCC 4.7 at least uses undecorated function names, so this cannot be used to hack together a solution. Pity.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing

```
cout<<mysteryMacro(std::string<wchar>);
```

you could write

```
cout<<"std::string<wchar>";
```

The only purpose I see is to get typeinformation inside a template, e.g.:

```
template<T>
void printT() {
    cout << "T is of type"<<mysteryMacro(T);
}
```

Since otherwise you automatically know the code.

This could be achieved with template specialization.

**Disclaimer**: this was untested, and is just a hint for what SHOULD work. I dont consider this a good solution. I am sure you can convert this to rather return strings than to print. A little more input on what you need this for would be great.

```
template<T>
void printT() {
    code that generates compile error, so you see that you have an undefined type
}

template<>
void printT<string>() {
    cout << "you have a <string>";
}
```

If you would like to use the template for variables you would hav to rely on automatic template parameter deduction like so:

```
template<>
void printT<string>(T) {
    cout << "you have a <string>";
}
```

and use it like this

```
int x;
printT(x);
```

eventhough I do not know why, since, as stated unless you are in a template you will know the type while writing the code and in templates the type is conveyed in the template parameters and thus knwon (not as string) and you could always write `printT<T>()`

Comment: I think OP wants `int x; printf("%s\n", MYSTERYMACRO(x));` to print `int`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: turning `void f<string>() {cout<<"string"}` into `char* f<string>() {return "string";}` should not be to hard, besides in the comments there is a link to a [solution](http://geometrica.saclay.inria.fr/team/Marc.Glisse/tmp/printtype.cpp) which is more elaborate, but uses this concept. I would take the comment from user gx_ as awnser.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: (sorry edit time was up) As for getting the type of of a variable of the variable you would have to rely on auto deducing template parameters. `template <T> func(T)` and use it with `func(x)`, where x is defined as `int x;`

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there are plenty of conceivable applications so I don’t understand the first half of your answer.